# Script not working on object in unity 2D

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, timer

I was following a tutorial where the gameobject was to spawn randomly within the screen. The code I used is as follows.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    // jump location support

    //screen dimensions 
    float minX = -3.77f;
    float maxX = 3.73f;
    float minY = -2.13f;
    float maxY = 2.16f;

    //timer support
    const float TotalJumpDelaySeconds = 1;
    float elapsedJumpTimeSeconds = 0;
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //update timer and check if its done 
        elapsedJumpTimeSeconds += Time.deltaTime;
        
        if(elapsedJumpTimeSeconds >= TotalJumpDelaySeconds)
        { 
            elapsedJumpTimeSeconds = 0;
            Vector3 position = transform.position;
            position.x = Random.Range(minX, maxX);
            position.y = Random.Range(minY, maxY);

        }


    }
}
```

[image]

But on running the game it stays in the same location

Here is the code in text

[image]

Comment: Code should be shared as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign your random position to your `transform.position` i.e.

```
        if(elapsedJumpTimeSeconds >= TotalJumpDelaySeconds)
        { 
            elapsedJumpTimeSeconds = 0;
            Vector3 position = transform.position;
            position.x = Random.Range(minX, maxX);
            position.y = Random.Range(minY, maxY);

            transform.position = position;
        }
```

I think your code can also be written as

```
        if(elapsedJumpTimeSeconds >= TotalJumpDelaySeconds)
        { 
            elapsedJumpTimeSeconds = 0;
            transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(minX, maxX),Random.Range(minY, maxY), transform.position.z);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Also in this LOC: transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(minX, maxX),Random.Range(minY, maxY), transform.position.z); we use new vector3 but why is it not used in the previous case? Do you need transform.position.z in unity 2d?

Comment: In case 1, you're already storing the position of your `transform` in your `position` variable, then changing the x and y values of `position` to random value, while keeping the z-value of `position` same as before i.e. `transform.position.z`.
We can use `Vector2` as well, it will not effect the z-value of your `transform`,
`transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(minX, maxX),Random.Range(minY, maxY));
`